# Parsing pair of strings fails. Bad spirit x3 grammar

Tags: c++, boost-spirit-x3

I would like to parse key-value pairs, mapping strings to strings. Since i want to support blocks of `{ ... }` for right hand sides i came up with a simple grammar to start with

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/std_pair.hpp>

namespace grammar::map
{
  using namespace boost::spirit::x3;
  auto expression = rule<class expression, std::pair<std::string, std::string>>{"expression"};

  auto lhs   =  *(~char_('='));
  auto rest  =  *(~char_(';'));
  auto block = '{' >> *expression >> '}';

  auto expression_def = lhs >> '=' >> (block | rest) >> ';';
  BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(expression)
}
```

But it fails to compile in combination, unless i change the attribute of expression to be `std::string`.

```
//! Transform a string into a key-value map of strings.
template <class M, class R>
  requires InputRange<R>() && _ContainerLike<M>
           && Same<value_type_t<M>, std::pair<const std::string, std::string>>()
           // && Assignable<std::pair<std::string, std::string>, value_type_t<M>>()
M parse(R&& range)
{
  auto begin = rng::begin(range);
  auto end = rng::end(range);
  auto map = M{};
  auto ret = x3::phrase_parse(begin, end, *grammar::map::expression, x3::space, map);
  if (!ret)
    throw std::runtime_error{"parse error"};
  return map;
}
```

I get the error

```
boost/spirit/home/x3/support/traits/move_to.hpp:62:18: error: cannot convert ‘std::remove_reference<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&>::type {aka std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >}’ to ‘char’ in assignment
             dest = std::move(src);
```

located from

```
boost/spirit/home/x3/support/traits/move_to.hpp: In instantiation of ‘void boost::spirit::x3::traits::detail::move_to_plain(Source&&, Dest&, mpl_::false_) [with Source = std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; Dest = char; mpl_::false_ = mpl_::bool_<false>]’:
```

Same thing happens if try the following expressions

```
auto pair = std::pair<std::string, std::string>{};
auto ret = x3::phrase_parse(begin, end, grammar::map::expression, x3::space, map);
```

I am coming to it since a couple of days and can not find out how to do it properly. I appreciate any help... :^)

Tested it with boost-1.60{-62} and gcc 6.1.1, 6.2 and a more less recent trunk version.

Comment: Nope, I alread include std_pair.hpp. I clarify that in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you have defined `expression` to have an attribute of `pair<string,string>`, but the synthesized attribute of `lhs >> '=' >> (block|rest) >> ';'` is `synt_attr=tuple<string,variant<vector<synt_attr>,string>>` which is basically `synt_attr=pair<string,variant<map_of_value_type_synt_attr,string>>`. So you have at least two options depending on the result you want:

- Change the synthesized attribute to be `pair<string,string>`. This is quite easy using the `x3::raw` directive [(running on WandBox)](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/WNfOYaZpSgfATgKb):

  ```
  auto expression_def = lhs >> '=' >> (raw[block] | rest) >> ';';
  ```
- Change your definition of `expression` to have an attribute compatible with the synthesized attribute. This requires the use of a recursive variant and complicates the way you need to access the data in the parsed map since you'll need to create a visitor [(running on WandBox)](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/xcSQD9q2wTHvPMC4).

  ```
  //A value is either a `string` or a `map<string,Value>`
  using Value = boost::make_recursive_variant<std::string,std::map<std::string,boost::recursive_variant_>>::type;

  ...

  struct printer : boost::static_visitor<void>
  {
      printer(int indent) :indent(indent) {}

      void operator()(const std::string& val) const
      {
          std::cout << std::string(indent, ' ') << val << std::endl;
      }

      void operator()(const std::map<std::string,Value>& val) const
      {
          for (const auto& pair : val)
          {
              std::cout << std::string(indent, ' ') << pair.first << ':' << std::endl;
              boost::apply_visitor(printer(indent + 4), pair.second);
              std::cout << std::string(indent, ' ') << std::endl;
          }
      }


      int indent;
  };

  void print_map(const Value& val)
  {
      boost::apply_visitor(printer(0), val);
  }
  ```

Comment: Yes that was the problem. Your raw-solution is really nice! ;-) Thank you again.