# Boost.Spirit: porting string pairs from Qi to X3

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi, boost-spirit-x3

I have the following working Qi code:

```
struct query_grammar
    : public boost::spirit::qi::grammar<Iterator, string_map<std::string>()>
{
  query_grammar() : query_grammar::base_type(query)
  {
    query = pair >> *(boost::spirit::qi::lit('&') >> pair);
    pair = +qchar >> -(boost::spirit::qi::lit('=') >> +qchar);
    qchar = ~boost::spirit::qi::char_("&=");
  }

  boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, std::map<std::string,std::string>()> query;
  boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, std::map<std::string,std::string>::value_type()> pair;
  boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, char()> qchar;
};
```

I tried porting it to x3:

```
namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
const x3::rule<class query_char_, char> query_char_ = "query_char";
const x3::rule<class string_pair_, std::map<std::string,std::string>::value_type> string_pair_ = "string_pair";
const x3::rule<class string_map_, std::map<std::string,std::string>> string_map_ = "string_map";

const auto query_char__def = ~boost::spirit::x3::char_("&=");
const auto string_pair__def = +query_char_ >> -(boost::spirit::x3::lit('=') >> +query_char_);
const auto string_map__def = string_pair_ >> *(boost::spirit::x3::lit('&') >> string_pair_);

BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(string_map_)
BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(string_pair_)
BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(query_char_)
```

but I am getting the following error when trying to parse a string with `string_map_` :

```
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/x3/support/traits/move_to.hpp:209: erreur : no matching function for call to move_to(const char*&, const char*&, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&, boost::mpl::identity<boost::spirit::x3::traits::plain_attribute>::type) 
     detail::move_to(first, last, dest, typename attribute_category<Dest>::type());
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I saw this answer: [Parsing pair of strings fails. Bad spirit x3 grammar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39780633/parsing-pair-of-strings-fails-bad-spirit-x3-grammar) and tried to make my string_pair raw but to no avail.

---

Edit:

this example code from the spirit examples does not compile either so I guess the problem is a bit deeper:

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
int main()
{
  std::string input( "cosmic  pizza  " );
  auto iter = input.begin();
  auto end_iter = input.end();
  std::pair<std::string, std::string> result;
  x3::parse( iter, end_iter, *(~x3::char_(' ')) >> ' ' >> *x3::char_, result);
}
```

Comment: mhh... something must be very wrong because when trying the string pair example on slide 42 here: http://ciere.com/cppnow15/using_x3.pdf it does not work either.

Comment: what is an example input

Comment: my original code is for parsing http requests: foo=bar&baz=boo

Comment: Cool. Looking at it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Qi Fixes

First off, I had to fix the rule declaration with the Qi variant before it could work:

```
qi::rule<Iterator, std::pair<std::string,std::string>()> pair;
```

For the simple reason that `value_type` has `pair<key_type const, mapped_type>` which is never assignable.

Here's a Qi SSCCE:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77c2ed5218b3d4c6)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp>
#include <map>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

template <typename T> using string_map = std::map<T, T>;

template <typename Iterator>
struct query_grammar : public qi::grammar<Iterator, string_map<std::string>()>
{
    query_grammar() : query_grammar::base_type(query)
    {
        qchar = ~qi::char_("&=");
        pair  = +qchar >> -(qi::lit('=') >> +qchar);
        query = pair >> *(qi::lit('&') >> pair);
    }

  private:
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::map<std::string,std::string>()> query;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::pair<std::string,std::string>()> pair;
    qi::rule<Iterator, char()> qchar;
};

int main() {
    using It = std::string::const_iterator;
    for (std::string const input : { "foo=bar&baz=boo" })
    {
        std::cout << "======= " << input << "\n";
        It f = input.begin(), l = input.end();
        string_map<std::string> sm;
        if (parse(f, l, query_grammar<It>{}, sm)) {
            std::cout << "Parsed " << sm.size() << " pairs\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
        }

        if (f != l)
            std::cout << "Remaining unparsed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
======= foo=bar&baz=boo
Parsed 2 pairs
```

### Qi Improvements

The following simpler grammar seems better:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/80e5127a70726b76)</kbd>**

```
template <typename Iterator, typename T = std::string>
struct query_grammar : public qi::grammar<Iterator, string_map<T>()>
{
    query_grammar() : query_grammar::base_type(query) {
        using namespace qi;
        pair  =  +~char_("&=") >> '=' >> *~char_("&");
        query = pair % '&';
    }

  private:
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::pair<T,T>()> pair;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::map<T,T>()> query;
};
```

It accepts empty values (e.g. `&q=&x=`) and values containing additional `=`: `&q=7==8&rt=bool`. It could be significantly more efficient (*untested*).

### X3 version

Without looking at your code, I translated it directly into an X3 version:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db558dcfb26bd907)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

template <typename T> using string_map = std::map<T, T>;

namespace grammar {
    using namespace x3;
    auto pair  =  +~char_("&=") >> '=' >> *~char_("&");
    auto query = pair % '&';
}

int main() {
    using It = std::string::const_iterator;
    for (std::string const input : { "foo=bar&baz=boo" })
    {
        std::cout << "======= " << input << "\n";
        It f = input.begin(), l = input.end();
        string_map<std::string> sm;
        if (parse(f, l, grammar::query, sm)) {
            std::cout << "Parsed " << sm.size() << " pairs\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
        }

        if (f != l)
            std::cout << "Remaining unparsed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
    }
}
```

Which, obviously ( --- ) prints

```
======= foo=bar&baz=boo
Parsed 2 pairs
```

### X3 Improvements

You should probably want to coerce the attribute types for the rules because automatic attribute propagation can have surprising heuristics.

```
namespace grammar {

    template <typename T = std::string> auto& query() {
        using namespace x3;

        static const auto s_pair  
            = rule<struct pair_, std::pair<T, T> > {"pair"} 
            = +~char_("&=") >> -('=' >> *~char_("&"));
        static const auto s_query
            = rule<struct query_, std::map<T, T> > {"query"}
            = s_pair % '&';

        return s_query;
    };

}
```

See it **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5985cb339b96cca4)</kbd>**

### What Went wrong?

The X3 version suffered the same problem with const key type in `std::map<>::value_type`

Comment: thanks for the improved grammar! the compile error I had was due to the missing include if other people stumble upon this: 
`#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp>` (also thanks @K-ballo).

Comment: No it wasn't: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/ (I'm quite aware of the includes)

Comment: I'm also wondering why the Qi version I posted (with a const std::string) does actually work for me.

Comment: Urgh. I was testing the wrong version for about 10 minutes ;) Here's confirmation that indeed the const key of `::value_type` is the hurdle for [your x3 version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2ca76f201b341233) (note the version in my answer/comment is stil better for the reasons described)